# mysql ERROR 1022 (23000): Can't write; duplicate key in table

Tags: mysql

I'm getting mad at this.

if I execute the create statement with foreign keys:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `asset` (
    ->   `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    ->   `CODE` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    ->   `DESCRIPTION` longtext,
    ->   `NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    ->   `SYSTEM_NODE_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `FUNCTIONAL_NODE_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `ZONAL_NODE_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `RESPONSIBLE_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `ORIGINATOR_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `INTERVENTION_PROGRESSIVE` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   `TICKET_PROGRESSIVE` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   `WORK_ORDER_PROGRESSIVE` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   `DEPOT_PROGRESSIVE` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    ->   UNIQUE KEY `UK_ASSET_CODE` (`CODE`),
    ->   FULLTEXT KEY `FT_ASSET` (`CODE`,`NAME`,`DESCRIPTION`),
    ->   CONSTRAINT `FK_ASSET_FUNCTIONAL_NODE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`FUNCTIONAL_NODE_ID`) REFERENCES `node` (`ID`),
    ->   CONSTRAINT `FK_ASSET_OWNER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`ORIGINATOR_ID`) REFERENCES `subject` (`ID`),
    ->   CONSTRAINT `FK_ASSET_RESPONSIBLE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`RESPONSIBLE_ID`) REFERENCES `subject` (`ID`),
    ->   CONSTRAINT `FK_ASSET_SYSTEM_NODE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`SYSTEM_NODE_ID`) REFERENCES `node` (`ID`),
    ->   CONSTRAINT `FK_ASSET_ZONAL_NODE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`ZONAL_NODE_ID`) REFERENCES `node` (`ID`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

But if I move the foreign keys after create table, everything is OK:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `asset` (
    ->   `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    ->   `CODE` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    ->   `DESCRIPTION` longtext,
    ->   `NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    ->   `SYSTEM_NODE_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `FUNCTIONAL_NODE_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `ZONAL_NODE_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `RESPONSIBLE_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `ORIGINATOR_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `INTERVENTION_PROGRESSIVE` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   `TICKET_PROGRESSIVE` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   `WORK_ORDER_PROGRESSIVE` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   `DEPOT_PROGRESSIVE` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    ->   UNIQUE KEY `UK_ASSET_CODE` (`CODE`),
    ->   FULLTEXT KEY `FT_ASSET` (`CODE`,`NAME`,`DESCRIPTION`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE `asset` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_ASSET_FUNCTIONAL_NODE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`FUNCTIONAL_NODE_ID`) REFERENCES `node` (`ID`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> ALTER TABLE `asset` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_ASSET_OWNER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`ORIGINATOR_ID`) REFERENCES `subject` (`ID`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> ALTER TABLE `asset` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_ASSET_RESPONSIBLE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`RESPONSIBLE_ID`) REFERENCES `subject` (`ID`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> ALTER TABLE `asset` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_ASSET_SYSTEM_NODE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`SYSTEM_NODE_ID`) REFERENCES `node` (`ID`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> ALTER TABLE `asset` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_ASSET_ZONAL_NODE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`ZONAL_NODE_ID`) REFERENCES `node` (`ID`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

## So, what's the difference?

I'm on `5.7.10-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)` under Windows 10.

Thanks

---

Obviously:

```
mysql> show variables like 'fo%';
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| foreign_key_checks | OFF   |
+--------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and this is the `show engine innodb status`:

```
mysql> show engine innodb status;

...

------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2017-03-22 13:14:17 0x26e4 Error in foreign key constraint of table edea2_atc/asset:
 FOREIGN KEY (`FUNCTIONAL_NODE_ID`) REFERENCES `node` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ASSET_OWNER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`ORIGINATOR_ID`) REFERENCES `subject` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ASSET_RESPONSIBLE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`RESPONSIBLE_ID`) REFERENCES `subject` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ASSET_SYSTEM_NODE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`SYSTEM_NODE_ID`) REFERENCES `node` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ASSET_ZONAL_NODE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`ZONAL_NODE_ID`) REFERENCES `node` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8:
Cannot resolve table name close to:
 (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ASSET_OWNER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`ORIGINATOR_ID`) REFERENCES `subject` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ASSET_RESPONSIBLE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`RESPONSIBLE_ID`) REFERENCES `subject` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ASSET_SYSTEM_NODE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`SYSTEM_NODE_ID`) REFERENCES `node` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ASSET_ZONAL_NODE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`ZONAL_NODE_ID`) REFERENCES `node` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: before create this table with foreign key you need to enter all foreign key in to it's parent table

Comment: That's not the reason. There's no **other** statement between the second `create table` and subsequent `alter table`.

Comment: ok I understand. you can create foreign key on only indexed column. So when you create table there is no index on any column. So after create table you need to first index then you can apply a foreign key

Comment: Wrong again. The same behavior applies even without indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the error.

Test:

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.17    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'foreign_key_checks';
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| foreign_key_checks | ON    |
+--------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SET @@SESSION.foreign_key_checks := 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'foreign_key_checks';
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| foreign_key_checks | OFF   |
+--------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `asset`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `asset` (
    -> `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    -> `CODE` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    -> `DESCRIPTION` longtext,
    -> `NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    -> `SYSTEM_NODE_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    -> `FUNCTIONAL_NODE_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    -> `ZONAL_NODE_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    -> `RESPONSIBLE_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    -> `ORIGINATOR_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    -> `INTERVENTION_PROGRESSIVE` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    -> `TICKET_PROGRESSIVE` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    -> `WORK_ORDER_PROGRESSIVE` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    -> `DEPOT_PROGRESSIVE` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    -> PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    -> UNIQUE KEY `UK_ASSET_CODE` (`CODE`),
    -> FULLTEXT KEY `FT_ASSET` (`CODE`,`NAME`,`DESCRIPTION`),
    -> CONSTRAINT `FK_ASSET_FUNCTIONAL_NODE_ID`
    ->     FOREIGN KEY (`FUNCTIONAL_NODE_ID`) REFERENCES `node` (`ID`),
    -> CONSTRAINT `FK_ASSET_OWNER_ID`
    ->     FOREIGN KEY (`ORIGINATOR_ID`) REFERENCES `subject` (`ID`),
    -> CONSTRAINT `FK_ASSET_RESPONSIBLE_ID`
    ->     FOREIGN KEY (`RESPONSIBLE_ID`) REFERENCES `subject` (`ID`),
    -> CONSTRAINT `FK_ASSET_SYSTEM_NODE_ID`
    ->     FOREIGN KEY (`SYSTEM_NODE_ID`) REFERENCES `node` (`ID`),
    -> CONSTRAINT `FK_ASSET_ZONAL_NODE_ID`
    ->     FOREIGN KEY (`ZONAL_NODE_ID`) REFERENCES `node` (`ID`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @@SESSION.foreign_key_checks := 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

**UPDATE**

In version 5.7.10 the error is generated.

**UPDATE 2**

> [Changes in MySQL 5.7.11 (2016-02-05)](https://lists.mysql.com/announce/1048)
>
> **InnoDB:** Creating a table with a full-text index and a foreign key constraint failed when foreign_key_checks was disabled. ([Bug #22094601](http://bugs.mysql.com/22094601), [Bug #78955](http://bugs.mysql.com/78955)).
>
> References: This bug is a regression of [Bug #16845421](http://bugs.mysql.com/16845421).